# Postgres undefined column when using CASE

Tags: postgresql

Using this SQL, I can cast a boolean column to a text:

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN bars.some_cond THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS some_cond_alpha
FROM "foos"
INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."id" = "foos"."bar_id";
```

So why do I get a `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "some_cond_alpha" does not exist` when I try to use it in a WHERE clause?

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN bars.some_cond THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS some_cond_alpha
FROM "foos"
INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."id" = "foos"."bar_id"
WHERE (some_cond_alpha ILIKE '%y%');
```

Comment: The alias is not visible for the where clause. Either you repeat the expression, or you use a subquery.

Comment: why would you even do that? just write `where bars.some_cond`

Comment: I don't really want to, but we're converting a lot of frontend logic, which is entirely based around text matching, to run on the server-side. The user can type in "laksdjflksadjl" and it has to match nothing.

Comment: And the query is ( as @Aツ remarked ) indeed nonsense. some_cond_alpha is either 'Yes' or 'No' , so there is no need for a ILIKE '%Y%' match.

Comment: @wildplasser Right, that's just an example; the user can type literally anything into the text field. There are a bunch of columns besides this one boolean one that have to do matching on. Maybe I'll just have to put this casting logic into one materialized view kind of table or something to make the querying and indexing simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the column is created on-the-fly and does not exist. Possibly in later editions of PG it will, but right now you can not refer to an alias'd column in the `WHERE` clause, although for some reason you can refer to the alias'd column in the `GROUP BY` clause (don't ask me why they more friendly in the `GROUP BY`)

To get around this, I would make the query into a subquery and then query the column OUTSIDE the subquery as follows:

```
select *
from (
    SELECT *, (CASE WHEN bars.some_cond THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS some_cond_alpha
    FROM "foos"
    INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."id" = "foos"."bar_id"
    ) x
    WHERE (x.some_cond_alpha ILIKE '%y%')
```

**NOTE:** It is possible at some point in the future you will be able to refer to an alias'd column in the `WHERE` clause. In prior versions, you could not refer to the alias in the `GROUP BY` clause but since 9.4 + it is possible...

Answer (score 2):

SQL evaluates queries in a rather counterintuitive way.  It starts with the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses, and only hits the `SELECT` towards the end.  So aliases defined in the `SELECT` don't exist yet when we're in the `WHERE`.  You need to do a subquery if you want to have access to an alias, as shown in Walker Farrow's answer.

When I read an SQL query, I try to do so in roughly this order:

1. Start at the `FROM`.  You can generally read one table/view/subquery at a time from left to right (or top to bottom, depending on how the code is laid out); it's normally not permissible for one item to refer to something that hasn't been mentioned yet.
2. Go down, clause by clause, in the order they're written.  Again, read from left to right, top to bottom; nothing should reference anything that hasn't been defined yet.  Stop right *before* you hit `ORDER BY` or something which can only go after `ORDER BY` (if there is no `ORDER BY`/etc., stop at the end).
3. Jump up to the `SELECT` and read it.
4. Go back down to where you were and resume reading.
5. If at any point you see a subquery, apply this algorithm recursively.
6. If the query begins with `WITH RECURSIVE`, go read the [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) for 20 minutes and figure it out.